# Django: Why does my validation error not show? The title is a unique field that is checked under clean_title, but it just redirects to the profile?

Tags: python, django, database

So my form redirects to my profile page, and the form is saved if has a unique title, however this validation error is not raised on testing.

Essentially my slug field is a primary key of sorts, with it being generated from the title in views.py. I know its not the best solution to a primary key, but I thought an easy way to make it unique was to ensure the title was too on form submission.

I've tried the old generate a unique slug, but that dosent seem to work either.

Forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["title", "content", "featured_image", "excerpt", "status"]

    def clean_title(self):
        title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        if Post.objects.filter(title=title).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Title already exists")
        return title
```

Views.py

```
class CreatePost(View):

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'create_post.html', {
            'post_form': PostForm,
        })

    def post(self, request):
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.slug = slugify(post.title)
            post.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile', args=[request.user]))
```

The Post Model from models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_posts"
    )
    featured_image = CloudinaryField('image', default='placeholder')
    excerpt = models.TextField(blank=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='blogpost_like', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_on"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

please be nice im not a pro dev... yet :)

Answer (score 0):

of course. You have always redirect:

```
 def post(self, request):
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile', args=[request.user]))
```

in your case it should be:

```
 def post(self, request):
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile', args=[request.user]))
   return render(request, 'create_post.html', {'post_form': form})
```

At first, you have an error on `get()`. In context you send `class PostFrom` and not the instance of this class. Right now it works, the template create empty instance of `class PostForm`, but the logic is wrong.

My opinion, try to use GCBV in your case `CreateView`. It is easier and you can not do stupid errors: the `CreateView` do it for you. :)

Read more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView